# How can I clear the an XML or Table?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, button, onclick

So I'm learning a bit of Javascript, and have tried a few different things to do this but can't quite get it. I would like the button to either toggle or have another button that can hide the xml in the table. So far I've tried to adding another button with an onclick function and set the function to clear. I've also tried to add an else statement with a function set to display = none. I am a total newb to javascript and Im still trying to work my way through learning it.

```js
// Groups Script
function showGroup() {
 "use strict";
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      groupFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "groups.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function groupFunction(xml) {
 "use strict";
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Book Title</th><th>Group Leaders</th><th>When Group Meets</th><th>Where Group Meets</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("GROUP");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("BOOK")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("LEADERS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("DAY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
 "<br />" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("TIME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("ROOM")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("group").innerHTML = table;
}
// Leadership Script
function showLeaders() {
 "use strict";
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      leaderFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "leadership.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function leaderFunction(xml) {
 "use strict";
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Leader</th><th>Ministry</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LEADER");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("MINISTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("EMAIL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
 "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("leaders").innerHTML = table;
}
// ministries script
function showMinistry() {
 "use strict";
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      ministryFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ministries.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function ministryFunction(xml) {
 "use strict";
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Name of Ministry</th><th>Leader</th><th>Target Audience</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("MINISTRY");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("LEADERS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("TARGET")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
 "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("ministry").innerHTML = table;
} 
// outreaches script
function showOutreaches() {
 "use strict";
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      outreachFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "outreaches.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function outreachFunction(xml) {
 "use strict";
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Name of Ministry</th><th>Leader</th><th>Target Audience</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("OUTREACH");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("PLACE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
 "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("outreaches").innerHTML = table;
}
// sermons script
function showSermon() {
 "use strict";
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      sermonFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "sermons.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function sermonFunction(xml) {
 "use strict";
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Name of sermon</th><th>Date</th><th>Who is Preaching</th><th>Notes</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("SERMON");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("PASTOR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
 "</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("NOTES")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
 "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("sermon").innerHTML = table;
}
//clear forms
function clearTable() {
 "use strict";
document.getElementById("group").reset();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Viral Ministries</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="xml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
 <img src="images/logoViral2.png" width="360px" height="180px" />
</div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="groups.xml">Groups</a></li>
   <li><a href="leadership.xml">Leadership</a></li>
   <li><a href="ministries.xml">Ministries</a></li>
   <li><a href="outreaches.xml">Outreaches</a></li>
   <li><a href="sermons.xml">Sermons</a></li>
   <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
 <table width="50%" height="auto" id="main" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <button type="button" onclick="showGroup()">Growth Groups</button><button type="button" onclick="clearForm()">Clear</button>
    <table id="group"></table>
   </td>
   <td>
    <button onclick="showLeaders()">Who Our Leaders are</button>
    <table id="leaders"></table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <button onclick="showMinistry()">What Ministries we Support</button>
    <table id="ministry"></table>
   </td>
   <td>
    <button onclick="showOutreaches()">Upcoming Outreaches</button>
    <table id="outreaches"></table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <button onclick="showSermon()">Upcoming Sermons</button>
    <table id="sermon"></table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which one is the problematic line? `document.getElementById("group").reset();` ??

Comment: You want to hide the table on click ?

Comment: Yes that was my last attempt at making it work.

Yes I want to hide the table on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hide the table you can do a function onClick

```
function hideTable() {
  document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'none';
}
```

When you want to display the table again just make another function with `display = 'block'`